# How to open run configurations window in Eclipse with shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

When I conduct multiple Java applications, I often need to open the

*Run -> Run Configurations*

to set the application input, or other parameters. So is there a way to open this window with shortcut ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set a custom shortcut for the *Run...* command:

- *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys*