# Shortcut for selecting run configuration in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, run-configuration

I have an Eclipse workspace with a bunch of projects. I manually created some run configurations for each project (it's necessary to pass some arguments to VM, so I can't just run it directly, e.g. using shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd> in the specific file).

Most of the time, I just use one run configuration (whereas for the first time I manually launch it using `Run -> Run configurations -> (name) -> Run`). Since I configured Eclipse to always run the last run configuration (on <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>), it's usually enough.

However, sometimes I need to switch to a different run configuration and then back to previous one and then to a different one etc. Is there a quick way to do it? I'd like to see a shortcut, which would display pop-up window with all existing run configurations. By typing first few letters, I'd find an appropriate one and would be able to immediately run it by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. I mean something similar to what <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> looks like.

I'm afraid there's not something like that. Nonetheless, any advice on how to get more effective would be greatly appreciated, because I'm bored of switching run configurations via menu (as I described above). I can press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> and then select a run configuration using arrow keys, but it's not really that comfortable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You already gave most of the answer yourself. Start by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> and then **simply start typing** the name of the configuration you want. The cursor should be positioned in the filter field and thus incrementally reduce the list of launch configurations as you type. When you've narrowed it down to 1, complete the selection by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

BTW: thanks for the reminder, I, too, was using the mouse way too much in this particular use case. I will stop doing so, now that I gave the answer :)

Comment: OMG, how could I overlook that search box? Thanks a lot!

Comment: To make it even more efficient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12606868/2709026 (binding a keyboard shortcut for opening Run configurations window). Personally, I chose `ALT+R`. Now it's perfect! `ALT+R`, start typing, `ENTER`. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + F11  to launch previously run configuration.

Comment: I followed the steps above and typed in the name of the configuration. Eclipse finds it but when I press `ALT+r` then "Browse" is selected and not Run. How can I press `ALT+R` instead of `ALT+r` ? `ALT+SHIFT +r ` is not working for me (Eclipse Neon 2)

Answer (score 4):

Since Eclipse 4.12 (June 2019, 4 years later) you can *also* launch any of the Run or Debug configurations available in your workspace from... the **Quick Access** menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> shortcut)

[image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/images/run-debug-quickaccess.png]

> Note: For performance reasons, the extra `Quick Access` entries are only visible if the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` bundle was already activated by some previous action in the workbench such as editing a launch configuration, or expanding the `Run As...` menus.