# "clean verify" option in m2e menu

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

My eclipse photon has m2e 1.9.0.20180606-2036. It shows the following menu if I open "Run As"

[image: My menu in Eclipse photon]

Interestingly, my *new* installation of Eclipse with exactly the same m2e version lacks the entry "clean verify", so all the Eclipses of my colleagues and all screenshots I found on the internet.

My question: May I have somehow changed this list, or am I experiencing a "bug"?

Actually, I found this entry convenient.

Comment: Not a bug I think but a new plugin version. You can workaround with option 3 and create a custom run configuration.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926894/shortcut-for-selecting-run-configuration-in-eclipse-ide) how to use the workaround.